# Mvvmcross(iOS) binding the Title of UIViewController

Tags: mvvmcross

Is it possible to bind the Title of a UIViewController to a ViewModel string property? It never seems to update. As a side issue, if you haven't set the title to something before the bind then there's a crash in the Mvvmcross code when set.Apply() is called.

The UIViewController has no .xib, I'm not sure if that's part of the problem.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
  base.ViewDidLoad();

  var set = this.CreateBindingSet<HomeView, HomeViewModel>();
  set.Bind(Title).To(vm => vm.ProjectName);
  set.Apply();
}
```

Here's the stack trace

> 2014-02-05 17:09:35.740 TerraFlex[9145:907] 02-05-2014 17:09:35:7403 :1: [Info] HomeView loaded
>   Thread started:  #12
>   2014-02-05 17:09:36.219 TerraFlex[9145:907] 02-05-2014 17:09:36:2190 :1: [Fatal] A critical error occurred and the application was closed
>   2014-02-05 17:09:36.250 TerraFlex[9145:907] 02-05-2014 17:09:36:2497 :1: [Fatal] Date: 5/02/2014 5:09:36 PM, [Exception]
>    Fatal
>    Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>    Stack:   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.Construction.MvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry.TryCreateSpecificFactoryBinding (System.Object target, System.String targetName, IMvxTargetBinding& binding) [0x00001] in c:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS\Cirrious\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding\Bindings\Target\Construction\MvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry.cs:69 
>     at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.Construction.MvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry.CreateBinding (System.Object target, System.String targetName) [0x00001] in c:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS\Cirrious\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding\Bindings\Target\Construction\MvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry.cs:22 
>     at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding.CreateTargetBinding (System.Object target) [0x00003] in c:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS\Cirrious\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding\Bindings\MvxFullBinding.cs:135 
>     at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding..ctor (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.MvxBindingRequest bindingRequest) [0x00014] in c:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS\Cirrious\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding\Bindings\MvxFullBinding.cs:60 
>     at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Binders.MvxFromTextBinder.BindSingle (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.MvxBindingRequest bindingRequest) [0x00001] in c:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS\Cirrious\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding\Binders\MvxFromTextBinder.cs:55 
>     at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Binders.MvxFromTextBinder+<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0 (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxBindingDescription description) [0x00000] in c:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS\Cirrious\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding\Binders\MvxFromTextBinder.cs:37 
>     at System.Linq.Enumerable+c__Iterator10`2[Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxBindingDescription,Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.IMvxUpdateableBinding].MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>     at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxBindingContextOwnerExtensions.AddBindings (IMvxBindingContextOwner view, IEnumerable`1 bindings, System.Object clearKey) [0x00028] in c:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS\Cirrious\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding\BindingContext\MvxBindingContextOwnerExtensions.cs:69 
>     at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxBindingContextOwnerExtensions.AddBindings (IMvxBindingContextOwner view, System.Object target, IEnumerable`1 bindingDescriptions, System.Object clearKey) [0x00019] in c:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS\Cirrious\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding\BindingContext\MvxBindingContextOwnerExtensions.cs:90 
>     at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxBindingContextOwnerExtensions.AddBinding (IMvxBindingContextOwner view, System.Object target, Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxBindingDescription bindingDescription, System.Object clearKey) [0x0000e] in c:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS\Cirrious\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding\BindingContext\MvxBindingContextOwnerExtensions.cs:83 
>     at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxBaseFluentBindingDescription`1[System.String].Apply () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxFluentBindingDescriptionSet`2[Trimble.TFM.FieldApp.HomeView,Trimble.TFM.FieldApp.Common.HomeViewModel].Apply () [0x00000] in :0

Thanks,
Jon

Comment: "It never seems to update. " - can you edit the question to show what code have you tried? "before the bind then there's a crash" - can you edit the question to show the "crash" and to include the stack trace of that "crash". Will try to help

Comment: I'll have to post the crash tomorrow but the code was pretty much like this.
`code`
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
      base.ViewDidLoad();
     
      Title = "" // set title first or set.Apply() crashes
      var set = this.CreateBindingSet<HomeView, HomeViewModel>();
      set.Bind(Title).To(vm => vm.ProjectName);
      // some other binding
      set.Apply()
    }
`code`
Thanks

Comment: Please "edit the question" to provide complete info including code and stack trace.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Fluent binding uses code like:

```
 set
    .Bind(<target object for bind>)
    .For(<property on target object>) // leave this out to use the "default binding property for the target object"
    .To(<property/expression on source object>)
    .WithConversion(<converter>, <converter parameter>) // optional
    .OneWay() // optional - also: OneWayToSource(), TwoWay() or OneTime()
    .FallbackValue(<value to use for UnsetValue>(); // optional
```

You can read more about this at:

- https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Databinding#wiki-fluent

---

Your binding is:

```
set.Bind(Title).To(vm => vm.ProjectName);
```

So you are binding:

- `.Bind(Title)` - whatever is in the current `Title` object (which will often be `null`)
- for whatever the default binding property is of that object - which depends on the object type - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/MvxTouchBindingBuilder.cs#L104 for the basic list
- to `ProjectName` on your DataContext (normally your ViewModel)

I guess what you wanted was:

```
set.Bind(this).For(v => v.Title).To(vm => vm.ProjectName);
```

I think you can also do this as:

```
set.Bind().For(v => v.Title).To(vm => vm.ProjectName);
```

---

With that said, the Mvx stack shouldn't really have barfed at having a `null` target and property - it didn't used to - so I'll add this as an issue to investigate and add a regression test for why `TryCreateSpecificFactoryBinding` can't handle `null`.

Comment: No - don't apologise - I'm sorry there was a crash and not some more meaningful error message! Thanks for reporting it - is in github issues now.